# how to make rust-analyzer recognize sub-folders

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

rust-analyzer recognizes examples folder , and what I want is to recognize it, sub-folders
like 'examples/borrowship/' so I can collect useful snippets and study under in one project,
is there any way ?
[image: vs code example folder]

Comment: From my experience, it should work also with subfolders by default - but you have to include them in the main as a module, e.g `pub mod mix.rs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `examples/` are analyzed by [Cargo target auto-discovery](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#target-auto-discovery). There is no way to expand the automatic behavior of looking for files (or directories with `main.rs` files) in `examples/`; you can only disable it entirely, or add individual targets manually.

Comment: thanks as a newbie I thought it is caused by rust-analyzer but this cargo book tip opened my eyes , I used cargo workspaces , so now I am able to divide by workspaces as "topic1/examples/" , "topic2/examples/" all in one cargo project